# In an AIR desktop app, is it possible to create a right click menu entry that a user can access when in another program?

Tags: actionscript-3

If I have my AIR desktop app running, is it possible to program it so that if I right click in another program eg Photoshop, the right click menu has an item in it from my program that allows me to do something in or with my program?

I notice that when I right click on my desktop there's a Dropbox item in the menu. So that sort of thing.

Thank you

Comment: In theory, you can: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: Thanks Organis. I was more meaning - can I code, with AS3, an AIR desktop app to do that so that when people install it on their computer they have an item in their right click menu that will perform a particular task in my program? Also, can my right-click item be made to be on all right click menus for all programs on a person's machine?

Comment: You can modify Windows Registry with your code, of course, but I did it like 20 years ago in Pascal/Delphi, so you'll have to figure this by yourself. Still, knowing it is possible is quite reassuring, right?

Comment: Please be responsible and make sure the installer provides a clearly visible option for having this feature enabled.